# Stop creation of the bean in external Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I have external (not my module) Spring @Configuration, that I Import in my module (@Import). In the external configuration, there are many beans that I want, except one, because I have the bean of that type (same class). There is no @ConditionalOn*** annotation on this bean, so I cannot manipulate the context this way.

The problem is that I can use @Primary on mu custom(internal) bean, but it does not solve my problem at all, because bean creation affects the other services that I am connected to.

Is this possible to stop bean creation in an Imported (external) configuration?

Comment: Exclude it in component scan? Sounds like there are more issues though, if just the creation of the bean is affecting other services...

Comment: This is some kind of imagined situation, please do not try to "over answer" the question :)

Comment: Why imagine a situation that shouldn't happen?

Comment: Ok, so if it would help you... Imagine that you have to use an external library, that had some awesome algorithms, but a dumb developer created configuration with "algorithm beans" and ONE bean that is super big overwhelming connection to the DB with hardcoded connection parameters. The library algorithms beans are changing often, so I want to just @import his configuration and don't care about changing it manually in my code each new algorithm versions. So I want to import whole import, but without the DBConnection bean. I can even go with solution "don't create every DBConnection class bean.

Comment: And I am very thankful for the advice (really), but for this problem, I don't need it. I want to know if it is possible to exclude the bean from the configuration. That's all.

Comment: I know this does not answer your question but something came in my mind. Might be useful. Name your bean and access it using the @Qualifier annotation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but pretty close the same thing does the @Primary annotation as I mentioned. The unwanted bean is still created, even if not used ;)